# Edit Nautilus Sidebar and Topbar

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, nautilus

I am working on my Senior project and have been doing a lot of research into editing Nautilus Files on Ubuntu 20.04 and I haven't found what I'm looking for. I want to edit the sidebar and add my own field, similar how `Starred` and  `Recent` are in Nautilus but not in terminal. I can't seem to find how to create something similar online. I want to use Nautilus-python or Nautilus-extension to be able to do this. I don't want to merely add a folder here.

The second part I want to add is a bookmark tab similar to one on Chrome or Firefox, I am aware there is already a bookmark tool in Nautilus but it doesn't let you add files to the bookmark and I rather have it at the top, right below the path/view options. Again I want to be able use the Nautilus-extensions/python.

I've looked into Nautilus.Column, FileInfo, Menu, MenuItem, ColumnProvider, MenuProvider etc, but they seem to only focus on the right click menu or the view of the main window of the file explorer. My main question is: what methods/attributes are out there from nautilus that could help me achieve this? Or what files from the given nautilus folder should I look into editing.